# what does autocorrelation matrix signifies in image processing?

Tags: matrices, matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find out corners using auto correlation matrix in an image,what does it signifies?

Comment: Loosely speaking, the autocorrelation tells you how much one part of the signal is related to other parts of it. If you look up material on the 1-D autocorrelation of some simple signals (e.g., sine waves), you'll develop an intuition for what I mean.